# Shortcut for styling multiple elements under one class in a stylesheet

Tags: css

Is there a shortcut in css for setting the stylesheet of multiple child elements under the same class or id?

For instance, if I have a form class, is there a shorter way of writing:

```
.form input, .form select, .form textarea {
 ...
}
```

Comment: You could use `.form *`.. but that would select all the children elements.

Comment: Yeah that wouldn't work since there would be different styles for labels/buttons but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a shortcut,  seems like nesting would be useful in this situation.

Comment: I don't know about shorter way but you might want to consider Sass with snippets and something like Sublime Text to be more productive as you can write short codes like `ul>li*5` and so on.. Once you tab it they expand to a fully formatted codes. They probably have it for CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

One option, you can use [scss](http://css-tricks.com/sass-style-guide/) to do pre processing the css to shorten and nest the selector.

```
.form {
    input {
        ...
    }
    select {
        ...
    }
    textarea {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is scss supported by browsers?  If not, how is it realized by the client?

Comment: scss is not supported by the browsers. It could only be read by the `command line prompt`. So the way it works is that you compile the `.scss` file to `.css` file using `Terminal`, and then use the compiled `.css`. Instruction on how to install can be found [HERE](http://sass-lang.com/install).

Note that scss is similar to sass, the only difference is that sass doesn't have `{` and `}` and it is aware of indentation.